# shapely, integer coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, shapely

I need to make shapely work only with integer coordinates. The problem happens when I try to rotate a LineString or MultiPoint with the integer coordinates, it returns me an object with the float coordinates.

Reason why I need only integers, to comapre coordinates to the pixels in cv2 canvas.

Comment: Does rounding not work for your situation?

Comment: When I round, after the rotation, some points get closer and rounding makes them the same coordinate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main problem is rotation. If the picture is 2-dimensional, you can calculate the rotation angle by using math and then use [getRotationMatrix2D](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) or [rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)